# Symfony FormType: how to get prototype in form type file

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony form type I have a `FormType` named

- KeywordType
- MessageType
- ReplyTextMessage
- ReplyImageMessage

and the code inside look like this

**KeywordType**

```
$builder
   ->add('messages', CollectionType::class, [
      'entry_type' => MessageType::class,
      'prototype' => true,
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'by_reference' => false,
   )]
```

**MessageType**

```
$builder
   ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
      'choices' => array_flip([
         'text' => ReplyMessageInterface::TEXT,
         'image' => ReplyMessageInterface::IMAGE,
      ]),
   )]
```

**Questions is**

How to get Prototype of `ReplyTextMessageType` and `ReplyImageMessageType` inside `MessageType`

because I want to get all of **ReplyMessageType** in the `form_theme`

If you don't understand my question I'll be here to answer any miss understand.

Thank you for your advance.

Comment: Question unclear! Please try to revise your, remove unnecessary parts and bold your requirement.

Comment: @Trix ah ok just a moment

Comment: @Trix The question is updated.

Comment: Please upload an image, representing the Interface you need. Alternatively you may explain the functionality of this section. What's the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solve!**

You must `getForm()` by used `$builder->create()` function then set that $builder->create() as an `array` and set attribute by use `$builder->setAttribute()`

And in function `buildView()` you just get attribute by use `$view->vars['nameAttribute']` and do like my code so your `form_theme` will have prototype

for more information please look at my code below

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => array_flip([
                'text' => self::TEXT_VALUE,
                'sticker' => self::STICKER_VALUE,
                'image' => self::IMAGE_VALUE,
            ]),
        ])
    ;

    $prototypes = [];

    $replyMessageTypes = [
        self::TEXT_VALUE => ReplyTextMessageType::class,
        self::STICKER_VALUE => ReplyStickerMessageType::class,
        self::IMAGE_VALUE => ReplyImageMessageType::class
    ];

    foreach ($replyMessageTypes as $name => $type) {
        $formBuilder = $builder->create(
            $name, $type, []
        );

        $prototypes[$name] = $formBuilder->getForm();
    }

    $builder->setAttribute('replyMessageTypes', $prototypes);
}

/**
 * @param FormView $view
 * @param FormInterface $form
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

    $view->vars['replyMessageTypes'] = [];

    foreach ($form->getConfig()->getAttribute('replyMessageTypes') as $type => $prototype) {
        /** @var FormInterface $prototype */
        $view->vars['replyMessageTypes'][$type] = $prototype->createView($view);
    }
}
```